# Positive Definite Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 & 3 \\ 4 & 2 & 5 \\ 3 & 5 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$$

Also suppose that I add a diagonal matrix $E$ to $A$ (that is consider $A+E$). If all the eigenvalues of $A+E$ are positive, will it be positive definite?

**Edit**. Adding a symmetric matrix to a diagonal matrix will be a symmetric matrix. So I can just add a large diagonal matrix get a positive definite matrix (e.g. so that all the eigenvalues are positive).

Comment: Depends on the $\mathbf E$ you're adding. The most negative eigenvalue of $\mathbf A$ is $\approx -3.04$, so for instance adding a matrix $c\mathbf I$, where $0 < c < 3.04$ would not yield a positive definite matrix. Nothing special about your $\mathbf E$?

Comment: @J.M. $E$ is a diagonal matrix is the only condition.

Comment: @J.M. Also adding a symmetric matrix to a diagonal matrix will be a symmetric matrix. And then if its eigenvalues are all positive then it will be positive definite.

Comment: Related .. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4336/if-eigenvalues-are-positive-is-the-matrix-positive-definite

Comment: So, you have answered your question, right?

Answer (score 1):

A symmetric matrix is positive definite if and only if all of its eigenvalues are positive. Therefore: if you add a diagonal (or just a symmetric) matrix $E$ to $A$, and find that all the eigenvalues of $A+E$ are positive, the conclusion will be that $A+E$ is positive definite.