# If $A$ is negative-definite, then for a sufficiently big $k>0$ the eigenvalues of $M = kA + B$ are all with negative real part?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I want to prove the next statement:

"If $A$ is a symmetric negative-definite matrix, then for a sufficiently big $k\in\mathbb{R}^+$, the eigenvalues of $M = kA + B$ are all with negative real part, where $B$ is just an arbitrary matrix with the appropriated dimensions. Assume further that $A$ and $B$ are real matrices."

I believe it is true since the intuition says that for a big $k$ you are making more negative the eigenvalues of $A = T kD T^{-1}$, where $T$ is just a transformation matrix and $D$ is the diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues of $A$. Since the eigenvalues are continuous functions of the elements of the matrix, $B$ can be considered as a small perturbation and then the eigenvalues of $M$ are still with negative real part.

Now I would like to prove it more rigorously and compute $k$ (it does not matter if it is conservative value). I guess one way can be looking at $M+M^T = k(A+A^T) + (B+B^T)$, if this matrix is negative-definite, then the eigenvalues of $M$ are with negative real part [[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188316/if-aat-is-negative-definite-then-the-eigenvalues-of-a-have-negative-real)], but I do not know how to proceed, any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $k$ should be sufficiently big in order to make $A$ "more dominant" and see $B$ as a small perturbation. Am I right?

Comment: If $B$ is not symmetric, then the eigenvalues might not all be real (for any $k$)

Comment: If $B$ is taken to be an arbitrary (the word is *arbitrary*, not random) **symmetric** matrix, then your argument regarding $k$ is sound.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I edited the question, I am asking for eigenvalues with negative real part (they can be complex indeed).

Comment: I think you have the right idea then

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, B is not symmetric, but indeed $B + B^T$ is and then we can look at $M+M^T$. What do you mean by "the argument regarding $k$ is sound?"

Comment: I mean that you have the right idea

Comment: A good way to get the bound you want is [Weyl's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality)

Comment: alternatively, it suffices to find a $k$ such that for real vectors $x$, $ x^TMx \leq 0$

Comment: This second approach works if both $A$ and $B$ are real matrices.  Is that the case here?

Comment: Yes, they are real matrices. Indeed Weyl's i equality provides a bound for $k$. Is the second approach less conservative?

Comment: It might actually provide the same bound. I'm not sure off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

We note that a real $M$ has eigenvalues with negative real part if $x^TMx < 0$ for all $x \in \Bbb R^n$ with $x \neq 0$.

We then see that
$$
x^T(kA + B)x = k(x^TAx) + x^TBx
$$
Let $\lambda = \lambda_{max}(A) = \min \left| \frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx} \right|$.
It suffices to take $k$ so that
$$
\left|k\lambda\right|  > \|B\| = 
\sup_{x \in \Bbb R \setminus \{0\}} \frac{\|Bx\|}{\|x\|} \geq
\sup_{x \in \Bbb R \setminus \{0\}} \frac{|x^TBx|}{x^Tx}
$$
So, we can take
$$
k >  \frac{\|B\|}{|\lambda|}
$$

Comment: Then, this bound for $k$ is independent of $A$? Interesting.

Comment: Whoops! It shouldnt be. I need to fix that.

Comment: see my latest edit.

Comment: Now I understand your argument. Thank you so much. I guess it should be $k |\lambda| > ||B||$ right?

Comment: @noether yes! fixed it again

Comment: By the way, I cannot see it the first statement of you answer. Should it be M has eigenvalues with negative real part if $x^T (M+M^T) x < 0$ ? and then make your computations for $M + M^T$?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot something else.  The trick is that I'm only using real $x$.  For any such $x$, 
$$
x^TMx = \frac 12 x^T(M + M^T)x
$$

Comment: Then, the conservative bound would be $k > \frac{\lambda_{max}(B+B^T)}{ |\lambda_{max}(A+A^T)|}$. From here, we can conclude that If $\lambda_{max}(B+B^T) < 0$, then any $k > 0$ would be valid right?

Comment: @noether yes.  More concisely, the set of (symmetric) negative-definite matrices form a cone.