# Eigenvalues of the sum of a symmetric and a anti-symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace, symmetric-matrices

Let $M_S$ be a symmetric and negative definite matrix and $M_A$ be an anti-symmetric matrix, both in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. The eigenvalues of $M_S$ lie in the negative part of the complex plane, while the eigenvalues of $M_A$ are found on the imaginary axis.

I'm interested in bounds for the eigenvalues of $M=M_S+M_A.$

Specifically, I want to know if we can say that the eigenvalues of $M$ will lie in the negative half of the complex plane. I thought this to be likely since 
$$\mathrm{tr}(M)= \mathrm{tr}(M_S)+\mathrm{tr}(M_A)=\mathrm{tr}(M_S),$$
i.e. it doesn't depend on $M_A,$ but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: [See: If $A+A^T$
is negative definite, then the eigenvalues of $A$
have negative real parts?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/188316/81360)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks for the link. I don't see the connection, however, since $M,$ $M_S$ and $M_A$ are completely unrelated, i.e., $M_S$ is *not* the symmetric part of $M,$ etc. Come to think of it, I know that $M=\frac{1}{2}(M+M^T)+\frac{1}{2}(M-M^T),$ but does that imply that $M_S=\frac{1}{2}(M+M^T)$ and $M_A=\frac{1}{2}(M-M^T)$?

Comment: Yes, we can deduce that $M_S = \frac 12 (M + M^T)$.  Notably, the symmetric and skew-symmetric matrices form two subspaces whose direct sum is $\Bbb R^{n \times n}$.

Comment: Or, if you prefer: note that
$$
(M_S + M_A) + (M_S + M_A)^T = M_S + M_A + M_S^T + M_A^T = M_S + M_A + M_S - M_A = 2M_S
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Huh, well that gives the result directly, thanks once again! (Again, feel free to post as an answer if you please.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

It is true that the eigenvalues of $M$ must lie in the left half of the complex plane because the symmetric matrix $M + M^T = 2M_S$ is negative definite.  The fact that $M + M^T$ is negative definite implies that $M$ has eigenvalues with negative real part is explained in [this question/answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/188316/81360).

Comment: I've asked another question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2454503/259085), that could be considered an extension of this one. I'd be very grateful if you'd take a look at it. Thanks.