# Why are the eigenvalues of $C=A+B$ bounded by the rectangle extended by the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

Consider the following equation of real $n\times n$ matrices
$$C=\underbrace{DM_S}_{A}+\underbrace{DM_A}_B,$$
where $D$ is diagonal and either positive or negative definite, and where $M_S$ is any symmetric matrix and $M_A$ is any anti-symmetric matrix.

We can prove that the eigenvalues of $A$ lie on the real axis and that those of $B$ lie on the imaginary axis, i.e., they are of the form
\begin{align}
\lambda_k^\uparrow(A)&=\alpha_k \\
\lambda_k^\uparrow(B)&=i\beta_k, 
\end{align}
where $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ and where $\lambda^\uparrow(\cdot)$ lists the eigenvalues in ascending order, such that $\lambda_1^\uparrow(\cdot)\leq\lambda_2^\uparrow(\cdot)\dots\leq\lambda_n^\uparrow(\cdot).$

> **Proposition:** The eigenvalues of $C$, $\lambda_k^\uparrow(C)=c_k=a_k+ib_k,$ lie within the rectangle extended by the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B,$ i.e.,
>   \begin{align}
> \alpha_1\leq &a_k \leq \alpha_n \\
> \beta_1\leq &b_k \leq \beta_n
> \end{align}
>   for all $k.$

**How can we prove this?**

> **Observation:** It also seems that $\alpha\succ a$ and $\beta\succ b,$ where $\succ$ is the majorization preorder, as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization). Perhaps this implies the proposition, while being easier to show?
>
> *Edit:* It *does* imply the proposition, since $y\succ x$ iff $x$ is in the convex hull of all vectors obtained by permuting the coordinates of $y,$ so **we can prove this instead.**

---

Simulations support this, but so far, I can't even get started with a proof. I looked in Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis*, because I thought some of the many inequalities in it might help. I didn't find anything, but I must admit that much of it went a bit over my head, so something of use may very well be in there.

**Here's an example** of the eigenvalues of $A,B,C$ viewed in the complex plane, for $n=6,$ where we can see the eigenvalues of $C$ being within the rectangle extended by the min/max eigenvalue on either axis:

[image]

**I tried loosening some of the demands** on $A$ and $B,$ as seen in the table below, where a $1$ means that the demand is made and $0$ means that it isn't, but I found counter-examples to the proposition for all the listed variations with a $0.$

For all variations, $A$ ($B$) has exclusively real (imaginary) eigenvalues. So, for instance, if $A=DM_S$ is not demanded, then $A$ is simply an arbitrary matrix with exclusively real eigenvalues. 
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|}
& A=DM_S & B=DM_A & D\text{ is diagonal} & \lambda_k(D)\gtrless 0 \forall k & \text{Same }D\text{ for both }A,B \\
\hline 
\checkmark & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\times & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\times & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\times & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots
\end{array}

**The motivation** behind proving this proposition is to prove what I wrote about in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2454503/259085).

Any input is highly appreciated!