# Proving that the sum of a normal, Hurwitz stable matrix and a skew-Hermitian matrix is again Hurwitz?

Tags: matrices, control-theory

Let $G$ be a complex normal matrix (that is, $GG^\dagger = G^\dagger G$) having all eigenvalues with strictly negative real part (i.e. is Hurwitz stable), and let $H$ be a skew-Hermitian matrix with the same dimensions as $G$ that does not necessarily commute with $G$.

I'm seeking to prove that $G + H$ is Hurwitz stable.

I'm able to come up with heuristic arguments based on physical intuition of the system I'm looking at, and I've verified the condition holds in trials where $G$ and $H$ are randomly generated, but a rigorous proof has eluded me.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to note that the matrix $(G + H) + (G + H)^\dagger$ is negative definite, as [is explained here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/188316/81360) (the proof is only given for the real case but can be extended to the complex case).

To see that this is true for our matrix, note that
$$
(G + H) + (G + H)^\dagger = G + G^\dagger + H - H = G + G^\dagger
$$
Because $G$ is normal, the spectral theorem implies that the eigenvalues of $G + G^\dagger$ will be $\lambda + \bar \lambda$ for all eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $G$.  That is, the eigenvalues of $G + G^\dagger$ are $2 \operatorname{Re}\{\lambda\}$ (for each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $G$).  Since these eigenvalues are negative and since $G + G^\dagger$ is Hermitian, we conclude that $G + G^\dagger$ is negative definite, as was desired.