# About linear subspace of Hurwitz Matrix Manifold

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, hurwitz-matrices

In this question I want to investigate the linear subspace of the Hurwitz matrix family.

That is to say, suppose $M_H = \{A \in R^{n \times n}: \operatorname{Re} \lambda_i(A) \leq 0, \forall i \leq n\}$ is the hurwitz matrix family, and $U, V$ are two matrices satisfying
\begin{equation}
    \forall \alpha \in R, U + \alpha V \in M_H
\end{equation}

What can we say about the matrix $V$ here?

This problem should have some untrivial solutions, since I have already proved that if $U$ is negative-definite and $V$ is skew-symmetric, then $U,V$ will satisfy the condition.

Remark:

1. What I considered here is only the real case. However it can also be helpful if you generalize it to general $M_n(C)$.
2. A proof of the case where $V$ is skew-symmetric can be find here: [Proving that the sum of a normal, Hurwitz stable matrix and a skew-Hermitian matrix is again Hurwitz?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2621393/proving-that-the-sum-of-a-normal-hurwitz-stable-matrix-and-a-skew-hermitian-mat)

Comment: Some sufficient conditions: 1 - both $U$ and $V$ are symmetric. 2 - both $U + U^T$ and $V + V^T$ are negative definite. 3 - $UV = VU$.

Comment: I think this is not the case. What I ask here is that $U + \alpha V$ has eigenvalues with nonpositive real part for every $\alpha \in R$, so this $\alpha$ here can be both positive and negative. Thus $V+V^T$ can not be negative definite.

Comment: You're right, my mistake