# Eigenvalue of the sum of symmetric and anti-symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'd like to get a rough estimation of eigenvalues of a structured matrix $A$, which is the sum of a symmetric and anti-symmetric (or skew-symmetric) matrix, i.e., $A = M + N$ where $M = M^T$ and $N = - N^T$.

In particular, I'm interested in the case where M is block-diagonal in the sense that $M = \begin{bmatrix} M_1 & \\ &M_2\end{bmatrix}$ and $N = \begin{bmatrix}  & N_1 \\ -N_1& \end{bmatrix}$. Further, I assume $M_1, M_2$ are symmetric positive-definite with the smallest eigenvalues $\mu_1, \mu_2$ respectively and $N_1$ has the largest eigenvalue $L$ (One example is $A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 5 \\ -5 & 6\end{bmatrix}$). In this case, it is known that all eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ can be written as the form of $\lambda_i = a_i + b_i j$, but what's the range of $a_i$ and $b_i$?

My guess: $a_i >= min\{\mu_1, \mu_2\}$ and $-L <= b_i <= L$. If so, is the lower-bound of $a_i$ sharp?

Comment: I suspect that section VI.2 of Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis* will have something relevant here

Comment: Actually it is relatively easy to see that your conjecture shows and that the bounds are sharp; I'll write something up when I have time

Comment: In a nutshell: note that if $B + B^*$ is positive definite, then the eigenvalues of $B$ must have positive real part.  Apply this to $B = A + \lambda I$ and $B = iA + \lambda I$ for real $\lambda$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188316/if-aat-is-negative-definite-then-the-eigenvalues-of-a-have-negative-real/188334#188334), if $B + B^*$ is positive semidefinite, then the eigenvalues of $B$ must have positive real part.

With that established, let $\mu = \min\{\mu_1,\mu_2\}$.  Note that $B = A - \mu I$ is such that $B + B^*$ is positive semidefinite.  It follows that the eigenvalues of $B$ have non-negative real part.  Note, however, that these eigenvalues are given by 
$$
\lambda_i(B) = 2[(a_i - \mu) + jb_i] .
$$
Similarly, setting $B = jA \pm L I$, we find that
$$
B + B^* = j2\pmatrix{0&N_1\\-N_1 & 0} \pm 2 L I.
$$
Verify that the eigenvalues of
$$
j\pmatrix{0&N_1\\-N_1 & 0}
$$
are given by $\pm \lambda_i(N_1)$. With that, applying the same logic as before lets us conclude that we must have $-L \leq b_i \leq L$ for all $i$, as you conjectured.

As for the sharpness of this bound: it suffices to consider the case of $M_1 = M_2 = N_1 = I$.