# Matrix properties and the smallest eigenvalue

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\lambda_{\min}$ be the smallest eigenvalue of the positive definite matrix $\mathbf{S}$, and $\|\mathbf{a}\|=r$. Then 
$$
\mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{S}\mathbf{a} > \frac{1}{2}\lambda_{\min} r^2 
$$

What properties of matrices were used to obtain the result? Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware of [Minimum and Maximum eigenvalue inequality from a positive definite matrix?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245866/minimum-and-maximum-eigenvalue-inequality-from-a-positive-definite-matrix)

Comment: You can find orthogonal matrix $U$ such that $U^tSU$ is diagonal with the eigenvalues of $S$ is the diagonal.

Comment: Thanks @MTurgeon, that gives $\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{S}\mathbf{a} \geq \lambda_{min}r^2$, where does the half come in?

Comment: @Mandy $\alpha\geq \frac{1}{2}\alpha$ for all non-negative $\alpha$.