# Product of positive matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have two positive-definite matrices $A$ and $B$ (not necessarily symmetric), and we have $AB=BA$, is there any theorem that ensures that the product of $A$ and $B$, $AB$ is positive definite? Or semi-positive definite?

Comment: For the symmetric case, see this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/113859/49610

That you don't require them to be symmetric is an interesting wrinkle, though.

Comment: Also, you may find this answer interesting: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/4351/13675

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ and $B$ are positive definite then for nonzero $x$ we have $x^TAx >0$ and $x^T Bx>0$ so that
$$x^TAxx^TBx >0$$
now
$$x^TAxx^TBx = x^TA\|x\|^2Bx =\|x\|^2(x^TABx) >0$$
Since $\|x\|^2>0$ is the length of $x$ we have that also $x^TABx>0$ for all nonzero $x$. Thus $AB$ is also positive definite.

Comment: $xx^T \ne x^Tx = \|x\|^2$.

Comment: @martini Ow yeah you're right, silly of me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this mistake in your derivation process but I don't know how to type in formula. But anyway thanks

Comment: No problem, sorry for the mistake. I will probably delete my answer as soon as a correct one pops up :)

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ and B are commutable, $AB=BA$, hence they are joint diagonalizable with a unitary matrix, $U$, $U^\dagger U=I$:

$A=U^\dagger D_A U$

$B=U^\dagger D_B U$

hence

$AB=U^\dagger D_A U U^\dagger D_B U=U^\dagger D_A D_B U$.

Now if entries of $D_A$ and $D_B$ are positive (nonnegative), i.e., $A$ and $B$ are P.D. (P.S.D.) then $AB$ is P.D. (P.S.D).